# Getting e.timeScale(...).unsubscribeVisibleTimeRangeChange is not a function

Tags: reactjs, function, unsubscribe, lightweight-charts

I am using **kaktana-react-lightweight-charts**, everything works perfectly until I got **e.timeScale(...).unsubscribeVisibleTimeRangeChange is not a function** error, as I did not implement it in my code. I do not know why I need this?.. The scenario was, At first my chart will displayed nicely as I wanted, then when I click at other data, it should display new data with same chart but instead I get this error. So I think I will implement **unsubscribeVisibleTimeRangeChange** function but dont know how..

```
<Chart

        lineSeries={this.getChartData1("line", mainData)}
        options={optionMaster}
        autoWidth
        height={indexMode ? 320 : 240}
        onCrosshairMove={(e) => this.createLineChart(e, mainData)}
        onClick={(e) => this.openWindow(e, mainData)} 
        ( ....unsubscriberVisibleTimeRangeChange..how to call from here?...)

      />
```

This is my **options**

```
    optionMaster: {
  alignLabels: true,
  localization: {
    dateFormat: "dd MMM 'yy",
  },
  handleScroll: {
    mouseWheel: false,
    pressedMouseMove: false,
    horzTouchDrag: false,
    vertTouchDrag: false,
  },
  handleScale: {
    axisPressedMouseMove: false,
    mouseWheel: false,
    pinch: false,
  },
  priceScale: {
    position: "left",
    autoScale: true,
    invertScale: true,
    alignLabels: false,
    borderVisible: false,
    borderColor: "#555ffd",
    scaleMargins: {
      top: 0.3,
      bottom: 0.25,
    },
  },
  timeScale: {
    fixLeftEdge: true,
    lockVisibleTimeRangeOnResize: true,
  },
},
```

Comment: Where did you find `unsubscribeVisibleTimeRangeChange` method? I don't see it in the docs

Comment: did you find a solution? i am facing a similar problem with the same error.